# Pino manually set level when logging

Tags: node.js, pinojs

How can I manually set the level of a log when using Pino?

Here's some sample code:

```
  const baseLogger = pino(loggerOptions);
  const activityLogger = baseLogger.child({ name: "activity" });
  const workerLogger = baseLogger.child({ name: "worker" });

  Runtime.install({
    logger: new DefaultLogger("INFO", (entry) => {
        workerLogger.error({
          level: entry.level.toLowerCase(),
          message: entry.message,
          timestamp: Number(entry.timestampNanos / BigInt(1000000)),
          ...entry.meta,
        })
      }
    )
  })
```

which produces logs like the following:

```
{"level":"error","time":1674573001943,"pid":95258,"name":"worker","level":"info","message":"Workflow bundle created","timestamp":1674573001943,"size":"0.70MB"}
```

Note that `level` appears twice. Ideally I'd like to invoke `workerLogger.log` and manually pass a `level` field but it seems pino does not make this easy. Is there a way to log with pino but not use one of the default level functions like `.info`, `.debug`, etc...?